# Websocket server Spring Boot

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, websocket

I am getting below error on testing WebSocket ServerEndPoint through Google Chrome.

> 2018-01-26 04:27:02 [http-nio-8090-exec-5] DEBUG
>   o.a.coyote.http11.Http11Processor - Error parsing HTTP request header
>   "java.io.EOFException: null   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1250)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1190)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:717)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:366)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:687)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I search it on Google and found, it happened when your URL too long but in my case it's not.

EndPoint URL: `ws://localhost:8090/ExchangeService`. The version of Tomcat embed inside Spring Boot is 8.5.23

Here is ServerEndPoint

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocket;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketHandlerRegistry;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig  implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) { registry.addHandler(context.getBean(ExchangeService.class), "/ExchangeService"); }

}
```

Comment: Can you post your code and add more information?

Comment: Added server end point code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved it by setAllowedOrigins("*") in WebSocket config

```
public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(context.getBean(TestWebSocket.class), "/ExchangeService").setAllowedOrigins("*");

    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your WebSocket endpoint doesn't work. Class `WebSocketConfig` should be like this

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {


    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/exchange_service");
    }

}
```

(I am using Spring Boot 2.0.0.M7)

for end-point `ws://localhost:8090/exchange_service`

Comment: ,I am not using stomp  messaging , Should i still enable it?